# Reading A stream through stream.read instead of using a StreamReader

Tags: c#, stream, io, httpwebrequest

I am trying to get a request and read it like:

```
byte[] buffer;
Stream read = http.GetResponseStream();
string readIt = read.Read(buffer, 0, read.Length)
```

But it throws an error with invalid argument.

Any idea how to get that response to a string while using Stream instead of a StreamReader?

Comment: It should refuse to compile (unassigned `buffer`)

Comment: @HenkHolterman: And trying to convert `int` to `string` too :)

Answer (score 5):

That's because you haven't created the byte array that you try to use.

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[read.Length];
```

Note though that you should check the value of `read.Length` before you use it. The response length is not always known.

Also, the `Read` method returns an `int`, not a `string`.

Also, and this is very important, you have to *use* the return value from the `Read` method, as it tells you how many bytes were actually read. The `Read` method doesn't have to return all the bytes that you ask for, so you have to loop until it returns the value zero, which means that the stream has been read to the end:

```
int offset = 0, len;
do {
  len = read.Read(buffer, offset, read.Length - offset);
  offset += len;
} while (len > 0);

// now offset contains the number of bytes read into the buffer
```